# JSON data not parsing correctly in C# Web API

Tags: javascript, json, web, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am currently following a tutorial online for creating a Telephone directory using Web API. Everything was working fine until I began to use javascript with knockout.js to bind my view model. Now no data is being loaded onto the page.

When I attempt to access a particular Telephone Directory id though a directory like `http://localhost:{port_no}/api/Data/1` my browser attempts to download the JSON data I am storing my data in.

Can someone please explain why this might be happening and why the JSON data is not being parsed correctly?

Controller class:

```
namespace TelephoneDirectory.Controllers
{
    public class DataController : ApiController
    {
        public async Task<IEnumerable<TelephoneEntry>> Get()
        {
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                return await context.TelephoneEntries.ToListAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task<TelephoneEntry> Get(int id)
        {
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                return await context.TelephoneEntries.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);
            }
        }


        public async Task<int> Post([FromBody] TelephoneEntry telephoneEntry)
        {
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                if (telephoneEntry.Id == 0)
                {
                    context.Entry(telephoneEntry).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Entry(telephoneEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return telephoneEntry.Id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

index.js (the code containing ko bindings)

```
function TelephoneEntry(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = data.id;
    self.firstName = data.firstName;
    self.lastName = data.lastName;
    self.number = data.number;
}

function TelephoneViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(0);
    self.firstName = ko.observable('');
    self.lastName = ko.observable('');
    self.number = ko.observable('');

    self.addText = ko.observable('Add');
    self.resetText = ko.observable('Reset');
    self.selectedIndex = -1;

    self.add = function () {

        var entry = new TelephoneEntry({
            id: self.id(),
            firstName: self.firstName(),
            lastName: self.lastName(),
            number: self.number()
        });

        if (self.addText() == 'Add') {
            self.telephoneEntries.push(entry);
        }
        else {
            var oldTelephoneEntry = self.telephoneEntries()[self.selectedIndex];
            self.telephoneEntries.replace(oldTelephoneEntry, entry);
        }

        self.post(entry);
        self.reset();
    };

    self.reset = function () {
        self.id(0);
        self.firstName('');
        self.lastName('');
        self.number('');

        self.addText('Add');
        self.resetText('Reset');
        self.selectedIndex = -1;
    };

    self.load = function () {
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:16257/api/Data/', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                self.telephoneEntries.push(new TelephoneEntry({
                    id: item.id,
                    firstName: item.firstName,
                    lastName: item.lastName,
                    number: item.number
                }));
            });
        });
    };

    self.post = function (telephoneEntry) {
        $.post('http://localhost:16257/api/Data/', telephoneEntry, function (id) {
            telephoneEntry.id = id;
        });
    };

    self.telephoneEntries = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.load();
}

ko.applyBindings(new TelephoneViewModel());
```

WebApiConfig class:

```
namespace TelephoneDirectory.App_Start
{
    public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();

            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            Database.SetInitializer(new Initializer());
        }
    }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/index.js"></script>

    <div class="container-narrow">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Telephone Directory</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row shaded padded">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: firstName" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: lastName" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: number" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <button id="add" name="add" type="submit" data-bind="click: add, text: addText">Add</button>
                <button id="reset" name="reset" type="reset" data-bind="click: reset, text: resetText">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-narrow">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: telephoneEntries">
                    <tr>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: firstName"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: lastName"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: number"></span></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.edit">Edit</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.delete">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>{"id":1,"firstName":"Jon","lastName":"Preece","number":"4444"}
```

Comment: no error, just that no data loads on the page and clicking the Add, Edit and Delete buttons seems to do nothing

Comment: apply databindings in document ready.

Comment: Open network tab and console tab in chrome or firebug and check what is send to browser

Comment: Ok ive pasted what comes back from network, the console tab was blank, there was an error with jquery.min.map in Network, but if I rename the file it loads properly. No data appears and buttons still do not work

Comment: I have added a screenshot for you reference

Comment: Hi @MatthewPigram, you could look at the content of the JSON data returned back when you request the service using the browser. If it is what you expect, then the issue is in your binding.

Comment: @ToanNguyen Something unusual happens when I run using Chrome as the browser. Chrome produces XML from the URL when I look at /api/Data/1 whilst IE 9 produces a JSON file which it attempts to download. The XML provides the expected data as does the JSON for IE

Comment: @MatthewPigram It's the content negotiation from the browsers, so everything is normal. To control the output format you can use fiddler http://fiddler2.com/. Now, back to the discussion, the issue is with your binding using KO not WEB API

Comment: @ToanNguyen I have added my html code to the question, as far as I can tell the bindings should be perfectly valid?

Comment: On a different note, your question has *a lot* of code to go through, most of it not relevant to the issue. Could you trim it down to only the relevant parts, make it into a *minimal* repro? Makes it a lot easier (or at least: inviting) for us to help you.

Comment: @Jeroen I have trimmed out some of the code, since i'm not exactly sure what the issue is there is still quite a bit there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the bindings on document ready, do the following.

Change this

```
ko.applyBindings(new TelephoneViewModel());
```

to this

```
$(function(){ 
    ko.applyBindings(new TelephoneViewModel());
});
```